# What is the Ker of application $f$ defined on $R_3 [X]$ as : $f(P) = P' + (X^2 + 2)P''(X)$ (I have an idea)?

Tags: vector-spaces

the question is, according to me, sufficiently clear. This looks basic and I looked for any polynomial deg(n) or less such that $P'+(X^2+2) P'' = 0$ and proceeded to solve this by integration (I must admit I first divided by $P'$, thereby excluding $P'=0$ as a possible path to finding a solution, which in this case would be a constant). My problem is I find $P' = Ae^{-arctan(\sqrt{2}x)}$. I can't find $P$ from this and wolframalpha's suggestion is rather scary-looking.
I probably didn't do this right. I would be very appreciative of any pointers.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(X)=a+bX+cX^2+dX^3\in \mathbb R_3[X].$ Then,
\begin{align}
f(P)=0&\iff b+2cX+3dX^2+(X^2+2)(2c+6dX)=0\\
&\iff 6dX^3+(2c+3d)X^2+2(6d+c)X+4c+b=0\\
&\iff(b,c,d)=(0,0,0).
\end{align}
Therefore, $$\ker(f)=\text{Span}\{1\}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, this also follows from the solution you found: namely that $P'=Ae^{-\arctan(\sqrt2 x)}$ with $A\in\Bbb R$, since the latter is only a polynomial when $A=0$.